# Using selenium with pyinstaller don't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I made a very simple script with authenticated proxy using selenium-wire. The script only opens a website to query the public ip. The problem is that when I use the script by running it as a script it works perfectly, but when I make it an executable with pyinstaller the script no longer works.

The code I use is this:

```
import time
from seleniumwire import webdriver


options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'http://tdt1RvAi59:VtSlkEIrJt@212.115.44.178:58542', 
        'https': 'https://tdt1RvAi59:VtSlkEIrJt@212.115.44.178:58542',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1' # excludes
    }
}


browser = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\t_t\\chromedriver.exe', seleniumwire_options=options)

browser.get('https://www.myip.com/')
```

And the error that appears when I run it after converting to .exe with pyinstaller is this:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.webDriveExceptions: Message: unknow error: net:: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
   <session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88>
[79696] Failed to execute script test
```

Does pyinstaller screw up selenium scripts somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Do the code work when options not used? maybe options is reason of error